# How do I run one specific spec in Spock? Using it with GEB and gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy, spock, geb

I'm creating a fairly large test suite using gradle, geb, and spock in conjunction. Gradle is obviously building and kicking off geb and spock, but I think that spock is where I can control and specify which Spec to run.

I'm building this based off of this starter.

https://github.com/AutomationSchool/geb-and-spock-automation-examples

How can I set this to run just one Spec?

Comment: just to make sure youve covered your bases, youve been here? i think gradle and maven can both receive the args passed in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35031820/run-a-specific-test-in-a-single-test-class-with-spock-and-maven

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Gradle's `Test` task takes a `tests` option](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/f2fae6ba563cfb772c8bc35d31e43c59a5b620c3/subprojects/testing-base/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/AbstractTestTask.java#L561). The supported patterns are documented in the [javadoc for `TestFilter`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestFilter.html). So if you want to run spec class called `MySpecToRun` in the project you linked to then you can do it this way:

```
./gradlew chromeTest --tests=MySpecToRun
```

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN